# Write asp.net tag in javascript block

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

This is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Home/Gallery";
$.getJSON(url, function (newProduct) {
    var contentNewProduct = $("ul.ei-slider-large");
    var smallNewProduct = $("ul.ei-slider-thumbs");
    $.each(newProduct.ja, function (index, data) {
        contentNewProduct.append('<li><img src="' + '<%:Web.HelperClasses.HelperClass.CheckImageUrlExist("' + data.PictureName10 + '")%>' + '" alt="image" /><div class="ei-title"><span class="productName">' + data.Name + '</span><span class="productPrice">' + data.Price + '</span><span class="productSpec"><br /><br />"' + '<%:Web.HelperClasses.HelperClass.TrimString(' + data.Notes + ',2)%>' + '"</span><span><a href="#" class="readmore">Read more...</a></span>' + '</div></li>');
    });
});
});
```

The error block `'<%:Web.HelperClasses.HelperClass.TrimString(' + data.Notes + ',2)%>'`, the error is `Too many characters in character literal`.

This is the form of function  :  `TrimString(string s,int total)` .

I tried to change to `'<%:Web.HelperClasses.HelperClass.TrimString("' + data.Notes + '",2)%>'` , but it still didn't work.

This is the c# `TrimString` function :

```
public static string TrimString(string str, int lenght)
{
string _str = str;
int _iAdditionalLenght = 0;
for (int i = lenght; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (_str.Substring(i, 1) == " ")
        break;
    _iAdditionalLenght++;
}
return str.Substring(0, str.Length < (lenght + _iAdditionalLenght) ? str.Length : (lenght + _iAdditionalLenght));
 }
```

This is what I tried in javascript,but it didn't work :

```
function TrimString(str, lengthStr) { 
  var _str = str;
  var _iAdditionalLenght = 0;
  for (var i = lengthStr; i < str.length; i++)
  {
      if (_str.substring(i, 1) == " ")
        break;  
      _iAdditionalLenght++;
  }

  return str.substring(0, str.length < (lengthStr + _iAdditionalLenght) ? str.length : (lengthStr + _iAdditionalLenght));
 }
```

Could any one tell me how can I write this function of `TrimString` in my block of javascript?

Thanks you so much.

Comment: var url = <%:= Url.Content("~/") %> + "Home/Gallery";

Answer (score 2):

If I guess right what your doing, you just can't. js is executed in client side, while aspnet is executed in server side. You can't create aspnet tags using js, because they need to be compiled and executed in server side.

If you just need a trim function, why not use jquery's built in trim function?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: Thanks Oscar, But in my `TrimString` function, I also include my own custom script. I added the block of the function to my question.

Comment: Well, you'll have to implement it in js if you want to use it in client side.

Comment: I did it in js ready Oscar, but the result didn't right like I did in C#.